# Checking derivation of y = a^x

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms, exponential-function

Can you tell me if there are any flaws with this derivation of $y = a^x$...

The assumptions are that the derivative $$\frac{d}{dx}e^x = e^x$$ and that the derivative  $$\frac{d}{dx}\ln x = \frac{1}{x} = x^-1.$$

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
y &=& a^x\\
\ln y &=& \ln a^x\\
\ln y &=& x \ln a\\
x &=&  \frac 1{\ln (a) }\ln y\\
\frac {dx}{dy} &=&  \frac {1}{\ln (a) } y^-1\\
\frac {dy}{dx}  &=& \ln(a)y\\
\frac {d}{dx} a^x &=& \ln(a)a^x
\end{array}
$$
I find the natural logarithm in this result very odd, a bit random.

Comment: Looks all good to me.

Comment: If $a=e$, then we have the familiar $y=e^x$ and its derivative $$\frac{d}{dx} e^x=\ln(e) e^x=1\cdot e^x=e^x.$$

Comment: Looks good, except... differentiation

Comment: A nitpick, use curly brackets like x^{-1} instead of x^-1 as you used... Otherwise very nice!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your work is correct. Notice also that we can differentiate this function by simpler way:

$$y=a^x=e^{\ln(a) x}$$
so using the chain rule
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\ln(a)e^{\ln(a) x}=\ln(a) a^x$$

Answer (score 0):

We start with y=a^x.  Taking natural logarithms of both sides.
              ln⁡y=ln⁡〖a^x 〗   using the “3rd” logarithm law.
              ln⁡y=x ln⁡a   Writing both sides with the base of e.
              y=e^(x ln⁡a ). Note this also equals a^x.   Now all we do is differentiate using d/dx (e^f(x)  )=f^' (x)e^(f(x)).
              y^'=ln⁡〖ae^(x ln⁡a ) 〗  or y^'=ln⁡〖a(a^x ).〗
                        ∎

Comment: I don't know why the word 2007 formatting didn't carry over here. My apologies.